# Python urllib2 trace route

Tags: python, network-programming, urllib2

I'm using Python and urllib2 to make POST requests and I have it working successfully. However, when I make several posts one after the other at times I get the error 502 proxy in use. Our company does us proxy but I'm not set up to hit the proxy since I'm working internally. Is there a way to get a trace route of how the POST request is being routed using urllib2 and Python?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "a trace route". `traceroute` is an IP thing, two levels below HTTP. And I doubt you want anything like that. You can find out whether there were any redirects, whether a proxy was used, etc., either by using a general-purpose sniffer or, much more simply, by just asking `urllib2`.

For example, let's say your code looks like this:

```
url = 'http://example.com'
data = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 'eggs'})
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
respdata = resp.read()
```

Then `req.has_proxy()` will tell you whether it's going to use a proxy, `resp.geturl() == url` will tell you whether there was a redirect, etc. Read [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) for all the info available.

Meanwhile, if you don't *want* a proxy, you can either disable whatever settings `urllib2` picked up that made it auto-configure the proxy (e.g., `unset http_proxy` before running your script), override the default handler chain to make sure there's no `ProxyHandler`, build an explicit `OpenerDirector` instead of using the default one, etc.